# How to get the original Perspective Projection Matrix

Tags: opencv, opengl, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

I am studying on 3D face reconstruction. the pipeline is blew.

[image]

usually, I can learn the Transform matrix, Rotation matrix, from the cropped face image, besides set the canera distance and FOV but how to get the calculate the Transform matrix, Rotation matrix, perspective projection matrix from the full image ?

or when cropping and scaling the roi face image  , how to get new projection matrix transformation derivation of the original perspective projection matrix

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do so just from the image. You would need to know the parameters of the camera. Also, it doesn't make sense to consider the transformation matrix, because transformation/rotation needs a reference system. But maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Crop the face Image， I  use  deep learning model to learn the  the  R  and T matrix，of  course I set the paramter of camera distance  and FOV  so I can get the Transform matrix, Rotation matrix, perspective projection matrix  from cropped image ,But I want to get R T and perspective projection matrix  from the full image . so I can render the full image